# Using OpenCV in QTCreator (linking problem)

Tags: opencv, qt-creator

I have a problem with the linking simpliest test program in QTCreator:

CODE:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <cv.h>

#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat M(7,7,CV_32FC2,Scalar(1,3));
    return 0;
}
```

`.pro` file:

```
QT       -= gui
TARGET    = testopencv
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2_1/include/opencv
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += C:/OpenCV2_1/lib/cxcore210d.lib \
    C:/OpenCV2_1/lib/cv210d.lib \
    C:/OpenCV2_1/lib/highgui210d.lib\
    C:/OpenCV2_1/lib/cvaux210d.lib
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I've tried to use -L and -l like `LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV2_1/lib -lcxcored`

And in `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:/OpenCV2_1/lib/Debug

LIBS += -lcxcore210d \
-lcv210d \
-lhighgui210d
```

The errors are like:

`debug/main.o:C:\griskin\test\app\testopencv/../../../../OpenCV2_1/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:97: undefined reference to cv::format(char const*, ...)'`

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

In Visual Studio it works but I need it works in QTCreator..

Answer (score 0):

Qt uses the MinGW compiler and linker. It will happily link OpenCV `.lib`s when you use the C interface. However due to [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) issues, it will not link C++ modules.

You will have to either restrict yourself to the C interfaces only (i.e. no `cv::Mat`), or get OpenCV to compile with MinGw (or compile Qt in/with VS). Also, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052762/opencv-2-1-with-qt-creator-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

This is what my .pro file looks like

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\release\\install\\include\

LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\release\\install\\bin \
    -lopencv_core240 \
    -lopencv_highgui240 \
    -lopencv_imgproc240 \
    -lopencv_features2d240 \
    -lopencv_calib3d240 \
```

and replace

```
#include <cv.h>
```

with

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
```

Above .pro file works perfect for me. I have used mingw to compile OpenCV and using mingw compiler tool chain in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that QtCreator cannot locate lib files.
Try specifying the include file and libs as follows.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2_1/build/include/

LIBS += C:/OpenCV2_1/build/gpu/x86/lib/cxcore210d.lib
```

you should refer to build folder if you're using pre-build version of opencv.

(I recommend pre-build version if you're not that familiar with opencv)